# OpenGL ES Error when running Qt Release mode

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, qt-creator

I'm using Qt 5.1.0 / Qt Creator 2.7.2 on Windows 10, and the compiler is msvc2010. I can run a new Qt Gui Application under Debug mode successfully, however, I can't run the same application under Release mode, which gives me the error:[image]

I'm confused about where I should look into to fix the issue.